# Count values that are filtered - Apache PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I have the following statement

```
Values = FILTER Input_Data BY Fields > 0
```

How to count the number of records that was filtered and not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- split into 2 datasets
SPLIT Input_data INTO A IF Field > 0, B if Field <= 0;

-- count > 0 records
A_grp = GROUP A ALL;
A_count = FOREACH A_grp GENERATE COUNT(A);

-- count <= 0 records
B_grp = GROUP B ALL;
B_count = FOREACH B_grp GENERATE COUNT(B);
```

Hope this will help!!